# scikit preprocessing across entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company': ['abc', 'xyz', 'def'], 
'Q1-2019': [9.05, 8.64, 6.3],
'Q2-2019': [8.94, 8.56, 7.09],
'Q3-2019': [8.86, 8.45, 7.09],
'Q4-2019': [8.34, 8.61, 7.25]})
```

The data is an average response of the same question asked across 4 quarters.

I am trying to create a benchmark index from this data. To do so I wanted to preprocess it first using either standardize or normalize.

How would I standardize/normalize across the entire dataframe. What is the best way to go about this?

I can do this for a row or column using but struggling across the dataframe.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

#define scaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler() #or StandardScaler

X = df.loc[1].T
X = X.to_numpy()

#transform data
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly your need, you can use [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) to apply the same transformation (e.g. scaling) separately to different columns.
As you can read from the linked documentation, you need to provide inside a tuple:

- a name for the step
- the chosen transformer (e.g. `StandardScaler`) or a `Pipeline` as well
- a list of columns to which apply the selected transformations

---

**Code example**

```
# specify columns
columns = ['Q1-2019', 'Q2-2019', 'Q3-2019', 'Q4-2019']

# create a ColumnTransformer instance
ct = ColumnTransformer([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler(), columns)
])

# fit and transform the input dataframe
ct.fit_transform(df)

array([[ 0.86955718,  0.93177476,  0.96056682,  0.46493449],
       [ 0.53109031,  0.45544147,  0.41859563,  0.92419906],
       [-1.40064749, -1.38721623, -1.37916245, -1.38913355]])
```

`ColumnTransformer` will output a numpy array with the transformed value, which were fitted on the input dataset `df`. Even though there are no column names now, the array columns are still ordered in the same way as the input dataframe, so it's easy to convert the array to a pandas dataframe if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @RicS's answer, note that what scikit-learn function return is a numpy array, and it is not a dataframe anymore. Also Company column is not included. You may consider this to convert results to dataframe again:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
x = scaler.fit_transform(df.drop("Company",axis=1))   # scale all columns except Company
y = pd.concat([df["Company"],pd.DataFrame(x, columns=df.columns[1:])],axis=1)  # adds results and company into dataframe again
y.head()
```